# Context issue with Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Beginner here.

I'm trying to implement a spinner with images using this guide;

https://dzone.com/articles/custom-spinner-for-android-application

I have it working correctly if implemented in my MainActivity.

The issues arise when I try to implement this within my fragment "Fragment1".

The code to initialize the spinner is as follows :

```
moodSpinner.adapter = MoodArrayAdapter(this, listOf(
            Mood(R.drawable.angry, "Angry"),
            Mood(R.drawable.happy, "Happy"),
            Mood(R.drawable.playful, "Playful"),
            Mood(R.drawable.wondering, "Wondering")
        )
    )
```

If that code is in my mainactivity.kt, and the spinner object with id moodSpinner in activity_main.xml, everything works fine.  If I move the code to my fragment.kt, and the spinner into the fragment.xml, it fails.

I suspect the issue is related to 'this' being used as the context.

"java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference"

I tried changing 'this' to 'this.requireActivity()' but no change.

Thanks.

Comment: Post complete code of your fragment and the error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.  To those suffering the same problem of context within a fragment, I solved it by doing two things.

First, I placed the above code into the 'onViewCreated' method, and not in the 'onCreate' method.

Secondly, I replaced 'this' with 'requireActivity().baseContext' to pass the correct context to the ArrayAdapter.

Revised code looks like ;

```
 moodSpinner.adapter = MoodArrayAdapter(requireActivity().baseContext, listOf(
            Mood(R.drawable.angry, "Angry"),
            Mood(R.drawable.happy, "Happy"),
            Mood(R.drawable.playful, "Playful"),
            Mood(R.drawable.wondering, "Wondering")
        )
```

Comment: By the way I have seen your answer. With fragments, you shouldn't set up any views (e.g. setup adapters into views) in `onCreate()`. Because in fragment's `onCreate()` the view has not been initialized. The fragment's view is initialized by `onCreateView()`. And in `onViewCreated()` is the most suitable time for you to set up things like adapters to the view, `onClick` of the view, ....